# How does quantum tunneling work in a bigger mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, estimation, quantum-tunneling

im trying to figure out the probability of a 9 y/o kid going right through an object. im trying to do this with a compacted form of schrodingers equation: e^(-2*(m*v/H/2pi)*l) where l = 22,34mm, h = plancks constant, m = 30 kg and v = 1,64 m/s
but everywhere i look it keeps saying it is 0,999... but it should be something REALLY tiny. could you help me? thx!

Comment: Units of l? Metres? Centimetres?

Comment: Units of l are milimeters

Comment: And, I just realized what I had done wrong, thank you!

Comment: So... is walking through walls is, technically, not impossible?

Comment: Yes, but more probable would be to have a vital organ go through; leaving the rest of you behind.

Answer (score 0):

Could you potentially have forgotten the exponent for planks constant? Or maybe got the sign wrong on it. I get near zero. Computationally it is so small it doesn't fit within the double precision limits of my computer calculator; registering an underflow error. Potentially you might be getting some computational undefined behaviour.